# How to skip Azure active directory authentication in Web API depends on Url request header value

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

How to skip the [Authorization](Azure AD authentication) from Web Api controller depends on the value from header request?

```
[Authorize]
public class ExampleController : ApiController
{
 //code
 private string _clientid;
 var req = Request.Headers;

 _clientid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.GetValues("clientid").First())
                        ? null :
                        req.GetValues("clientid").First();
}
```

The above mentioned _clientid  is a header value, I want to skip authentication for some _clientid  values.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you essentially have an alternative way of authentication.

It would make the most sense to define your own authentication scheme that checks that header and creates a user principal based on that.

Then you can keep on using `[Authorize]` as usual.

Writing an example would be quite time-consuming, the best I can offer at the moment is the Security repo, which contains all of the built-in authentication schemes, like JWT Bearer here: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerHandler.cs Check those for examples on how to implement an authentication handler.

Comment: Is it possible to do any custom routing of that controller,depends on header value?, instead of custom authentication

Comment: Maybe you *could* do it with some kind of middleware that checks whether there is a user authenticated, and if not, changes the request path before it hits MVC. But I would still recommend my approach, as it will allow you to use all of the framework's tools, instead of working past them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom authentication handler similar to the one [here](https://zogface.wordpress.com/2016/09/13/custom-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-core/) .

Then, where you add authorization in Startup.cs, you can add a custom policy like this:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(
            o =>
            {
                // create a policy called ApiKeyPolicy which requires a Role defined in 
                // ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.
                // The policy is used by the API controllers.
                o.AddPolicy(
                    "ApiKeyPolicy", builder =>
                    {
                        builder.AddAuthenticationSchemes(
                            ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationSchemeName);
                    });
            });
```

and add the scheme to the `services.AddAuthentication` builder:

```cs
builder.AddScheme<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions, ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler>(
            "ApiKey", "ApiKey", o =>
            {
                o.AllowedApiKeys = config["Api:AllowedApiKeys"];
                o.ApiKeyHeaderName = config["Api:ApiKeyHeaderName"];
            });
```

In my example, I have an `ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions` class that is configured with some API keys and the http header name to check. In your case, you would probably want the valid client IDs.

Finally, you need to tell the `[Authorize]` attribute which policy is needed:

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = "ApiKeyPolicy")]
```

In your case, you want to be able to handle both the client IDs and regular auth, so you could add the regular auth scheme to the policy builder expression (the first snippet above).